# CentOS 6.5 Network Configuration

Tags: networking, centos, dhcp

I've been trying to install CentOS 6.5 on a computer at work for the past couple weeks, but I'm getting stuck at configuring the newtork. I can't get an IP via DHPC. If I setup everything to be static, I get the network icon but not network at all (I can't even ping the gateway).

Maybe I'm missing something? It's a fresh install, and I have trying editing the network-scripts manually and also via the network manager tool. None seems to work, but it all works fine on my Windows computers, even with DHCP.

The router is at 172.16.0.100, subnet 255.255.255.0 and the computer IP could be anything, but I'm using 172.16.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

As root what is the output of ifconfig?

This will display what networking devices have been configured by the system and what the status of them is.

Answer (score 0):

service NetworkManager start;
chkconfig NetworkManager on

ip addr
or
ifconfig eth0 #ip  up

or install  and use webmin